# Specifying a value greater than 7% makes the column widths uneven. Can someone explain why?

Tags: html, css, layout

This is the page in question:

http://codepen.io/virtuoso/pen/uyckh

At the bottom of the page, there are three DIVs (Content 1, Content 2, Content 3) with `display:table-cell` and `width: 1%`. I have two questions regarding them:

1. Even though the `width` is `1%`, each one occupy 1/3rd of the width of the container. Why?
2. If I change the `width` to `50%`, the first two cells expand to cover about 80% of the container and are both the same width, while the third one becomes very narrow. If the `width` is set to `100%`, the first cell becomes 80% wide, and the other two are now the same width and occupy the remaining space. Why this strange behaviour? I was expecting all three DIVs to be equally wide in all cases. What's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - By default, table-cells (or element displayed as them) will fill their container completely, so assigning a width to them may be considered as a "relative" assignment more than a standard "absolute" assignment. So, if their width sum is less than 100%, they will share the remaining width.

2 - Same here, if their sum width is more than 100%, they will try to take all the available space (starting from the first td, then the 2nd, and so on). The fact that they don't implements "overflow:hidden" CSS attribute implies that the third TD (the one who should use the remaining 0% of available width) will be displayed just to wrap its content.

Comment: I just tested this using normal table/tr/td syntax, and those TDs behaved the same way as well. You are absolutely correct.